# Is javax.persistence.entitymanager is a JPA interface?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

Today I've confused. is javax.persistence.entitymanager a JPA interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's [an interface](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html), and Hibernate provides [an implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/ejb/EntityManagerImpl.html).